# Angular UI bootstrap modal is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to angular and bootstrap. This is my [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/82WdYsqfhPMTDPwitY82?p=preview).
This is my code of DemoController:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('demoController', function($modal) {
    this.message = 'It works!';

    key = 1000;

    this.modalInstance = this.modal = function(){
      $modal.open({
        controllerAs: 'modalController as modal',
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        resolve: {
          key: function() {
            return key;
          }
        }
      });


    };

     this.modalInstance.result.then(function (optionSelected){
        if(optionSelected == 'yes')
        {

        }
      });
  });
```

ModalController:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('modalController', function($scope, $modalInstance, key) {


    $scope.featureName = key;

            $scope.yes = function () {
                $modalInstance.close('yes');
            };
            $scope.discard = function () {
                $modalInstance.close('discard');
            };
            $scope.goback = function () {
                $modalInstance.close('goback');
            };
});
```

Modal.html:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">



  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Do you want to save the changes to {{featureName}} </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="yes()">Yes</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="discard()">Discrad</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="goback()">Go Back</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</script>
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.16" data-semver="1.2.16" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.11.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="demoController as demo">
    <h1>{{ demo.message }}</h1>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="demo.modal()">Open modal</button>



  </body>

</html>
```

I want to pass data from demo controller to modal controller. I want to have separate html and controller for the modal dialog. Somehow this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working plunker based on your own plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/VDDyDuBoZ30tAk2kQKoc?p=preview

List of changed things:

- In `index.html`, I added `Ctrl.js` to the list of loaded scripts.
- In `modal.html`, removed the script tags surrounding the html. When loading the modal html from an external file, the script tags aren't necessary.
- Finally in `script.js` made a few changes, ending up with the following:

  ```
  angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('demoController', function($modal) {
    this.message = 'It works!';

    var key = 1000;

    this.modal = function() {
      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        controller: 'modalController',
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        resolve: {
          key: function() {
            return key;
          }
        }
      });
      modalInstance.result.then(function(optionSelected) {
        if (optionSelected === 'yes') {
          console.log("Yes selected!")
        }
      })
    }
  });
  ```

Basically, `this.modal` is the function that's executed when clicking on the Open modal button. In the function, we initialize a variable `modalInstance`, which is the `$modal.open` function call. We also handle the modal result inside the `this.modal` function, not outside of it.

Answer (score -2):

You have a lot of mistakes there. Here is your example:

plnkr.co/edit/47WJrWHW7ueYXBpiYJbA?p=preview